# how to deploy already developed drupal project into server

Tags: php, html, drupal-7, content-management-system

I have created drupal project site in my local system.I want to move this site into remote server.

I tried move to server. what i did "copy the all files into publi_html folder" .its taking install.php and coming from scratch . can you please help me how to move my drupal project into server.

Thanks and Advance.

Comment: import your database and make db connection in settings.php

Answer (score 0):

When moving your Drupal installation from one server to another, you have to edit your /sites/default/settings.php file. There are instance and server specific settings in there that need to be changed.

Comment: If, by your answer, you don't have a settings.php file, then you need to look closer at your local installation in general, including your local default.settings.php. The quick list of things you need to change are your database settings and your site URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Go to cpanel and create your database.Then import your database to it.
Then you can make connection settings in sites/default/settings.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to J.R and Sweta ranja for giving reply,

By default its not there setting.php in my drupal project, i copied default.setting.php and renamed as setting.php and deployed into server.

Do i change any thing in setting.Php?  please tell me what i change in setting.php

Answer (score 0):

You will need to

1. move all you files to your server
2. move your database
3. edit your sites/default/settings.php where change your db settings
4. you might need to change settings in your /.htaccess file